# Using a python script as a command line argument for another python script

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have an already written python script that returns an integer value.  I would like to use that integer value as one of the arguments of a different python script I am working on.  Is there a way to do this?  I am working in terminal for mac.

Comment: 'returns an integer value'. *How* does it return that value? Please share your code.

Comment: why not just import your script into the second script? call the function that returns an integer from within the second script.

Comment: @ecline6 I just looked up how to import and it looks very simple.  Can I call the name of the variable I am returning in the new script?  If not, how do you interact with the variables of the imported script?

Answer (score 0):

Just import your script as a module into the second script. Then you can call any functions with the module prefix.
From within script 2:

```
import script1

#this is your function call that returns an integer
script1.script1function()
```

You can use:

```
from script1 import *
```

to have access to all the variables as well.  But this is usually not a good idea especially if you plan to change the value of those variables.

Comment: You would need to do "from script1 import *".  This will give you access to all the variables as well as functions.  Generally, this is not a good idea though...

Comment: would i actually be typing the * or is it a placeholder for the variable name, function name I want to import.  also, do you still interact with script1's stuff in the same way? e.g.,

Comment: Yes, you actually type the "*", but again you have to be careful with working with vars from other scripts.  If you're just reading the value, it's usually ok, but python won't prevent you from using the same namespace in another script.

Comment: Also, please select an answer if your problem has been solved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by importing the first script as a module in the second ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html))
Let's say your first script is called script.py and looks like this:

```
def some_function():
    return(1)

some_variable = 2
```

In your second script, you can import the first one as a module and use its functions and variables, when prepended by the module name:

```
import script

print script.some_function(), script.some_variable
```

This will print `1, 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import (
    Popen,
    PIPE
)
p1 = Popen(['/path/to/python', "/path/to/your/script.py"], stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.read()
```

But your script need stdout,
That means it must print result